# how to send text to textarea in div element using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: Screenshot of div element which has hidden textarea]

How can I send text or provide input to the `textarea` box using **Selenium Automation**?

It is a `div` element with `style="overflow:hidden"`. I have tried using XPath, but it did not work for me.

**How can I provide input to the `textarea` shown in the image?**

Comment: Can you please add  the HTML tag Details?

Comment: Can you provide it manually ?

Comment: Yes I can provide text manually

Comment: What is the xpath you're using?

Comment: Right click on element>inspect>copy XPath.                                 element = findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="notebook-container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre"));

Comment: That's your problem right there, if you expect your xpath to point to textarea, it should **end** with textarea. You're pointing to something far deeper in the code. Get the correct xpath and try your code again.

Comment: @MivaScott  To be more precise it is the textarea of Jupyter notebook so you can run it in your machine. I want to send text in input area of Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input_area']//textarea"))
      .sendKeys("Your Value");
```

Comment: It did not work. To be more precise it is the textarea of Jupyter notebook so you can run it in your machine

Comment: What you mean by did not work ? Please let us know error which you are getting while execute it,

Comment: Error is : text is not sent to textarea of jupyter notebook. It is showing null value

Comment: Yes, NullPointerException of which element ? It might be possible, it throws some another issue.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='input_area']//textarea"}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mistaken on a few things:

1. You don't send text to the div, you send it to the textarea.
2. The textarea does not have a style of hidden*. It is quite visible in the screenshot you provided.
3. The parent div does not have a style of hidden either*. If it did, you couldn't see the child textarea.
4. The parent div **does** have `style="overflow: hidden"` which only hides the content that cannot be seen within it's 'box', but it does not hide the whole element.

I hope this helps. I recommend brushing up on HTML and CSS before going farther in trying to automate the page.

*There could be an external CSS file that could apply the style of hidden, but since we can see the textarea in the screenshot, I don't believe this is the case.

Comment: I know that we don't sent text to div, its textarea to where text is sent. But the problem is I am not able to send it, might be because element is not captured using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `textarea` the parent elements above it located inside a `frame`. Please do check the HTML code of your page and look for any frames wrapping the `textarea`.

If so, you can temporarily switch to the frame before doing `sendKeys()`:

`driver.switchTo().frame(arg)`. You can choose from any of the signatures below.

```
/**
 * Select a frame by its (zero-based) index. Selecting a frame by index is equivalent to the
 * JS expression window.frames[index] where "window" is the DOM window represented by the
 * current context. Once the frame has been selected, all subsequent calls on the WebDriver
 * interface are made to that frame.
 *
 * @param index (zero-based) index
 * @return This driver focused on the given frame
 * @throws NoSuchFrameException If the frame cannot be found
 */
WebDriver frame(int index);

/**
 * Select a frame by its name or ID. Frames located by matching name attributes are always given
 * precedence over those matched by ID.
 *
 * @param nameOrId the name of the frame window, the id of the &lt;frame&gt; or &lt;iframe&gt;
 *        element, or the (zero-based) index
 * @return This driver focused on the given frame
 * @throws NoSuchFrameException If the frame cannot be found
 */
WebDriver frame(String nameOrId);

/**
 * Select a frame using its previously located {@link WebElement}.
 *
 * @param frameElement The frame element to switch to.
 * @return This driver focused on the given frame.
 * @throws NoSuchFrameException If the given element is neither an IFRAME nor a FRAME element.
 * @throws StaleElementReferenceException If the WebElement has gone stale.
 * @see WebDriver#findElement(By)
 */
WebDriver frame(WebElement frameElement);
```